# How to export zone files from a Plesk 10.4 Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: domain-name-system, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a Plesk windows server and I want it to work with my 3 existing nameservers. I have configured the name-servers to accept zone-files exported from the Windows server but I do not know how to make the windows server export zone files to them. My research has led to making a batch file which I schedule with the windows task scheduler.

My questions are:

1)What is the location of Plesk zone files on a Windows 2008 R2 Plesk server?
2)What do I include in the batch file to achieve this? I need a typical zone exporting script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SCRIPT
1)
Install Unxtils
In the directory I have installed  c:\UnxUtils\bin\sh\  (its the default) which I downloaded from http://www.redantigua.com/unxutils-win.html

2) Using notepad add the script to the zone directory and name it appropriately (e.g gen-secondaries.sh)

```
 #!/bin/sh
MASTER=10.1.1.1 ( IP of your server)
NAMED_ROOT=c:/program files (x86)/Parallels/Plesk/dns/etc/
HTTPDOCS=c:/inetpub/vhosts/default/htdocs
egrep "^zone" $NAMED_ROOT/named.conf |egrep -iv "arpa|\"\." | gawk -F\" '{print $2}' > $NAMED_ROOT/domains
echo > $HTTPDOCS/secondariescp8.txt
for i in `cat $NAMED_ROOT/domains`; do
echo "zone \"$i\" {" >> $HTTPDOCS/
echo " type slave; " >> $HTTPDOCS/secondariescp8.txt
echo " file \"/var/named/slaves/$i.hosts\";" >> $HTTPDOCS/secondariescp8.txt
echo " masters { $MASTER; };" >> $HTTPDOCS/secondariescp8.txt
echo " allow-transfer { none; };" >> $HTTPDOCS/secondariescp8.txt
echo "};" >> $HTTPDOCS/secondariescp8.txt
echo >> $HTTPDOCS/secondariescp8.txt
done
chmod 644 $HTTPDOCS/secondariescp8.txt
```

NB secondariescp8.txt is where I store my zone files.

3) Schedule the script. I used Plesk scheduler wit the arguments below:

- Path to executable file *:C:\UnxUtils\bin\sh.exe
- Arguments:"C:\Program files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\dns\etc\gen-secondaries.sh"

Hope this helps someone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

1) C:\Program Files (x86)\Parallels\Plesk\dns\var\ is the location for the Zone file on my test server for a test domain.